# Iterate over a map decoded from PHP-serialization format

Tags: php, go, deserialization

How I can read ***conditions*** unserialised data in golang in map format?

```
[map[19:map[conditions:map[0:map[operator:== value:AMW-1900-50SLE-ROOM 
is_value_processed:false type:feedexport/rule_condition_product 
attribute:sku] 1:map[type:feedexport/rule_condition_product 
attribute:sku operator:== value:ASL-B654-77-74-98-ROOM 
is_value_processed:false] 2:map[is_value_processed:false 
type:feedexport/rule_condition_product attribute:sku operator:== 
value:ASL-B217-57-54S-95-ROOM]] type:feedexport/rule_condition_combine 
attribute:<nil> operator:<nil> value:1 is_value_processed:<nil> 
aggregator:any]]]
```

This is the code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/wulijun/go-php-serialize/phpserialize"
)

func main() {
    rules := RulesList()
    for _, rule := range rules{
        fmt.Println(rule.Conditions.(interface{}))
    }
}

type Rule struct {
    RuleId     int         `json:"rule_id"`
    Conditions interface{} `json:"conditions"`
}

func RulesList() ([]Rule) {
    db := DbConn()
    res, err := db.Query(`SELECT r.rule_id, r.conditions_serialized AS 
    conditions FROM m_feedexport_rule AS r`)
    CheckError(err)
    rule  := Rule{}
    rules := []Rule{}
    for res.Next()  {
        var ruleId int
        var conditions string
        err = res.Scan(&ruleId, &conditions)
        CheckError(err)
        cons, err := phpserialize.Decode(conditions)
        CheckError(err)
        rule.RuleId     = ruleId
        rule.Conditions = cons   
        rules = append(rules, rule)
    }
    return rules
}
```

**The result is ok but I need it in map form, now this is the interface which I can't loop over.** In case if anyone don't understand the code, ask me.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're talking about the type of the variable `cons`, are you?

### Background

If yes, the reason its type is `interface{}` is because in PHP, it's possible to serialize a value of any type (from bare integer to a complicated object), and hence any deserialization code must cope with it. Since in Go the so-called "empty interface", `interface{}`,
is satisfied by any type at all (including any custom type implemented by a programmer), it's sensbile for a decoder of PHP-serialized data to return a value of type `interface{}`.

### Solution

After making sure decoding succeeded,
you need to either [type-assert](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions)
the resulting value to a type you need or to use
a [type switch](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_switches)
to diverge processing based on the concrete type of the
value returned by the decoder.

The approach is very well demonstrated by the
package you're using in its own [test suite](https://github.com/wulijun/go-php-serialize/blob/master/phpserialize/decoder_test.go).

A snippet from it demonstrating the basic approach

```
if decodeRes, err = Decode(result); err != nil {
    t.Errorf("decode data fail %v, %v", err, result)
    return
}
decodeData, ok := decodeRes.(map[interface{}]interface{})
if !ok {
    t.Errorf("decode data type error, expected: map[interface{}]interface{}, get: %T", decodeRes)
    return
}
obj, _ := decodeData["object"].(*PhpObject)
if v, _ := obj.GetPrivateMemberValue("a"); v != int64(1) {
    t.Errorf("object private value expected 1, get %v, %T", v, v)
}
if v := obj.GetClassName(); v != "A" {
    t.Errorf("object class name expected A, get %v", v)
}
```

Here, `decodeRes` is what returned by the decoder.
That value is then type-asserted to make sure it's concrete type
(also called "dynamic" — meaning "at runtime") is
`map[interface{}]interface{}`.

> Note that the so-called "two-argument" type assert is used
>   (it's also called a "comma-ok idiom") to not make the program
>   panic at runtime in case the concrete type is different from
>   the expected (always do this on data fetched from outside!).

The value of the type-asserted concrete type is stored in the
`decodeData` variable, and then that variable is inspected further.